# Laravel SQL Server connection with ENCRYPT=yes trustServerCertificate=true

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel

I got a ubuntu docker container which runs php 5.5.9, laraverl 5.2 which can connect successfully to SQL Server and get results back.

The docker image I am using is https://hub.docker.com/r/h2labs/laravel-mssql/

The problem I got is that the server uses encryption and I cant find how to pass the following parameters to the laravel connection string for mssql

```
ENCRYPT=yes;trustServerCertificate=true
```

My SQL Server connection string at present looks like this

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=sql.mydomain.com
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=mydbname
DB_USERNAME=mysusername
DB_PASSWORD=mypass
```

My laravel database config looks like this

```
        'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

The SQL Server error log entry is

> Encryption is required to connect to this server but the client library does not support encryption; the connection has been closed. Please upgrade your client library. [CLIENT: 103.31.114.56]

Comment: have you tried to them to your `.env` file

Answer (score 10):

Support for either option was not introduced [until Laravel 5.4](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.4.18/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/SqlServerConnector.php#L121); Specifically, [v5.4.11](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/0804f42a3fc1df286256e94b9d84decd4d69253b#diff-828954f72fa14c48217530801632b772)

So you would first need to upgrade to laravel/framework:>=5.4.11,<5.5

Then, to configure your application, you will need to modify your config/database.php file as follows:

```
// ...
'sqlsrv' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encrypt' => 'yes', // alternatively, defer to an env variable
    'trust_server_certificate' => 'true', // alternatively, defer to an env variable
],
// ...
```

DatabaseServiceProvider, via ConnectionFactory and SqlServerConnector will use this to build the underlying PDO connection with those options set in the DSN.

Comment: Not sure this is right though. Laravel 5.4 will need php version > 5.5.9 which will mean certain packages will not be avail on the image I work on. Can you provide a link to an image with a working setup>

Comment: Which packages are problematic?  PHP 5.5 reached end of life on [21 July 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Release_history), so it's probably easier to work around those packages.