# Laravel: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

Here's the complete error message:

> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.

I've a private company project, currently the project is developed using CodeIgniter3 and the database uses Microsoft SQL Server. I need to turn the project into Laravel9. So, I follow several instruction until meet some tutorial here:

- [Laravel migration cannot find driver when using sqlsrv database in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49333044/laravel-migration-cannot-find-driver-when-using-sqlsrv-database-in-windows) (the last answer seems suitable to my problem)
- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098 (here's the driver for PHP7, but my project uses PHP8.0 so, I download the other file)

The installation didn't face much problem. I follow the procedure from the first list with the suitable driver. But then facing the error as mentioned above.

Comment: SQL Server instances are, by default, installed with self-signed X.509 certificates. So how have you configured your [Connection Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/connection-options)? You would have three options: 1) get the public key portion of the certificate from the server and add it to your Trusted Certificates store, or 2) use `TrustServerCertificate=1`, or 3) use `Encrypt=0`. `Encrypt=0` is the least desirable option because all of your SQL Server communications will be sent across the network unencrypted, i.e.: "in the clear".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

i found the solution here:
[Laravel SQL Server connection with ENCRYPT=yes trustServerCertificate=true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43359009/laravel-sql-server-connection-with-encrypt-yes-trustservercertificate-true)

it also working for laravel 9, update the config file `config/database.php` like below

```php
'sqlsrv' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encrypt' => 'yes',
    'trust_server_certificate' => true,
],
```